# Can SQL Server CONVERT null values from JAVA to 0?

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a decimal column in database. I wanna pass a null value from java and convert it to 0 in sql. I've tried ticking off 'allow nulls' while passing null value from java but it gives me an error saying 'column does not allow nulls'. Can SQL Server automatically convert java null values to 0? I'm using SQL Server 2014. Thanks.

Comment: Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp, you can use these in the SQL to manage.

Comment: ISNULL(Value,0)

Comment: I mean without running a query. Like in the column settings itself.

Comment: decimal column in database set it Allow null its also remove error

Comment: or set default value to 0

Comment: Checking allow null then default value to 0 still saves the value as null

Comment: Did you consider adding a trigger to your table?

Comment: @Tyron78 Thank you. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding an INSTEAD OF INSERT Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IOI_MyTable ON MyTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MyTable
       SELECT ISNULL(Col1, 0), ISNULL(Col2, 0), ...
       FROM inserted
END;
GO
```

Comment: I don't have access to the data being inserted until it is in the database. Is this applicable?

Comment: `inserted` is an internal table, which includes all columns you used in your insert - so basically yes, it should be applicable for you. :-)

Comment: I have more than 50 columns in this table, do I really have to write them all?

Comment: At least it's the safest way. However, you can generate the SELECT statement in SQL Server Management Studio and then change only the required value columns to ISNULL()...

Comment: Please see my edited answer, I've tested it and is working. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Looks OK except the dropping of the column ID?! Is it an identity column? Anyways, I still think it's better understandable / debuggable to use the full SELECT statement instead of creating a temp table from inside of the trigger... your choice. :-)

Comment: Will I encounter problems later about the identity column?

Comment: No, I don't think you will experience problems.

Answer (score 0):

From Tyron78's answer,
I have used instead of trigger to catch insert statements into the table then change the null value to 0 using ISNULL().

But since my table has a lot of columns and I do not have time as of now to write it all down :), I had to put the data in a temporary table and DROP the identity column.

```
 ALTER TRIGGER checkNull ON <table>
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM inserted
        UPDATE #tempTable SET <column> = ISNULL(<column>,0)
        ALTER TABLE #TempTable
        DROP COLUMN id
      INSERT INTO <table>
           SELECT *
           FROM #tempTable
    END;
    GO
```

However, I will mark Tyron78's as the solution because it is more understandable/debuggable

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original question, some explanation of what you've done and why would help.